# Implementing Open-id server with multiple provider

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.9

I want to implement an openid server which could interact with multiple providers to authenticate users. Basically I am looking for something like StackOverflow does for login.

I was looking into ruby-openid but it does not seem to be maintained with last commit 2-3 years back. 
Can someone suggest me good gem /plugin or resource for implementing Open-id in Rails 3.2

**Requirement :**

1. Should be able to host my own open id server
2. Allow user to use multiple options like(google/ blogger / yahoo..etc)
3. Should work well with Rails 3.2 / ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Just came across a nice blog differentiating Oauth and Openid, thought of sharing it 
http://cakebaker.42dh.com/2008/04/01/openid-versus-oauth-from-the-users-perspective/

Comment: anybody answer that helpful to you then accept that answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few useful gems:

- [OAuth](https://github.com/oauth/oauth-ruby)
- [OmniAuth](http://www.omniauth.org/)

P.S. [ruby-openid](https://github.com/openid/ruby-openid/) is actially well maintained - last commit 18 days ago... ;)
You can include it in your application from it's Git Repository by adding this line into your Gemfile:

```
gem 'ruby-openid', :git => 'https://github.com/openid/ruby-openid.git'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try OmniAuth

http://www.omniauth.org/

or you can also user RubyCAS Server

http://code.google.com/p/rubycas-server/

Answer (score 0):

Try This OmniAuth and See Video you can easily Understand and implement

Part - 1 : http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1

Part - 2 : http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2